# Best practices for hard-coded strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I am writing a ruby script where I read commands from command line and check if they are correct. If not I show  the proportionate error.

My code looks like this:

```
if command == 0
   puts "error one #{command}"
elsif command == 1
   puts "other error two #{command}"
...
end
```

I have a lot of different error-strings and they have ruby code in it. 
I was thinking to create a hash but I can not add ruby code in the error-string.

Is there any better way to manage (hard-coded) error-strings?

Answer (score 2):

If the code is always going to be at the end, then this might work:

```
Errors = {
  0 => "error one",
  1 => "other error two",
}.freeze

# later...

command = 1
puts "#{Errors.fetch(command)} #{command}"
#=> other error two 1
```

Otherwise, you can add a custom placeholder and later substitute in the error code:

```
Errors = {
  0 => "error %{code} one",
  1 => "%{code} other error two",
}.freeze

def error_str_for_code(code)
  Errors.fetch(code) % { code: code.to_s }
end

# later...

command = 1
puts error_str_for_code(command)
#=> 1 other error two
```

Comment: hmm I think the second answer solves my problem. Thank you.